# Erro ao executar react-native run-android --deviceId=XXXX - Task :lottie-react-native:androidJavadocs FAILED

Tags: react-native

Quando eu executo react-native run-android sem informar o device, o app funciona sem exceções, mas caso executo o comando com --deviceId, ele não passa nas tasks do lottie.

Erro:

```
> Task :lottie-react-native:androidJavadocs FAILED
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:8: error: package androidx.core.view does not exist
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
                         ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:13: error: package com.airbnb.lottie does not exist
import com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView;
                        ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:14: error: package com.airbnb.lottie does not exist
import com.airbnb.lottie.RenderMode;
                        ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:15: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
                                ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:16: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
                                ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:17: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray;
                                ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:18: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
                                ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:19: error: package com.facebook.react.common does not exist
import com.facebook.react.common.MapBuilder;
                                ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:20: error: package com.facebook.react.uimanager does not exist
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager;
                                   ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:21: error: package com.facebook.react.uimanager does not exist
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
                                   ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:22: error: package com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations does not exist
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;
                                               ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:23: error: package com.facebook.react.uimanager.events does not exist
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.RCTEventEmitter;
                                          ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
class LottieAnimationViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<LottieAnimationView> {
                                         ^
  symbol: class SimpleViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
class LottieAnimationViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<LottieAnimationView> {
                                                           ^
  symbol: class LottieAnimationView
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
  private Map<LottieAnimationView, LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager> propManagersMap = new WeakHashMap<>();
              ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:6: error: package com.airbnb.lottie does not exist
import com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView;
                        ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:7: error: package com.airbnb.lottie does not exist
import com.airbnb.lottie.LottieDrawable;
                        ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:8: error: package com.airbnb.lottie does not exist
import com.airbnb.lottie.LottieProperty;
                        ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:9: error: package com.airbnb.lottie does not exist
import com.airbnb.lottie.RenderMode;
                        ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:10: error: package com.airbnb.lottie does not exist
import com.airbnb.lottie.SimpleColorFilter;
                        ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:11: error: package com.airbnb.lottie.model does not exist
import com.airbnb.lottie.model.KeyPath;
                              ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:12: error: package com.airbnb.lottie.value does not exist
import com.airbnb.lottie.value.LottieValueCallback;
                              ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:13: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray;
                                ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:14: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableMap;
                                ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:15: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableType;
                                ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:16: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ColorPropConverter;
                                ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
  @Override public LottieAnimationView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {
                                                          ^
  symbol:   class ThemedReactContext
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
  @Override public LottieAnimationView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {
                   ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
  private void sendOnAnimationFinishEvent(final LottieAnimationView view, boolean isCancelled) {
                                                ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:113: error: cannot find symbol
  public void receiveCommand(final LottieAnimationView view, int commandId, final ReadableArray args) {
                                   ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:113: error: cannot find symbol
  public void receiveCommand(final LottieAnimationView view, int commandId, final ReadableArray args) {
                                                                                  ^
  symbol:   class ReadableArray
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:193: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setSourceName(LottieAnimationView view, String name) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:206: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setSourceJson(LottieAnimationView view, String json) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:211: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setCacheComposition(LottieAnimationView view, boolean cacheComposition) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:216: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setResizeMode(LottieAnimationView view, String resizeMode) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:229: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setRenderMode(LottieAnimationView view, String renderMode) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:242: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setProgress(LottieAnimationView view, float progress) {
                          ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:247: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setSpeed(LottieAnimationView view, double speed) {
                       ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:252: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setLoop(LottieAnimationView view, boolean loop) {
                      ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:257: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setImageAssetsFolder(LottieAnimationView view, String imageAssetsFolder) {
                                   ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:262: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setEnableMergePaths(LottieAnimationView view, boolean enableMergePaths) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:267: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setColorFilters(LottieAnimationView view, ReadableArray colorFilters) {
                              ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:267: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setColorFilters(LottieAnimationView view, ReadableArray colorFilters) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class ReadableArray
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:272: error: cannot find symbol
  protected void onAfterUpdateTransaction(LottieAnimationView view) {
                                          ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:277: error: cannot find symbol
  private LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager getOrCreatePropertyManager(LottieAnimationView view) {
                                                                        ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
  private final WeakReference<LottieAnimationView> viewWeakReference;
                              ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
  private ReadableArray colorFilters;
          ^
  symbol:   class ReadableArray
  location: class LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
  private RenderMode renderMode;
          ^
  symbol:   class RenderMode
  location: class LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
  public LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager(LottieAnimationView view) {
                                            ^
  symbol:   class LottieAnimationView
  location: class LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setRenderMode(RenderMode renderMode) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class RenderMode
  location: class LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
  public void setColorFilters(ReadableArray colorFilters) {
                              ^
  symbol:   class ReadableArray
  location: class LottieAnimationViewPropertyManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottiePackage.java:3: error: package com.facebook.react does not exist
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
                         ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottiePackage.java:4: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist     
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
                                ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottiePackage.java:5: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist     
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
                                ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottiePackage.java:6: error: package com.facebook.react.bridge does not exist     
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
                                ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottiePackage.java:7: error: package com.facebook.react.uimanager does not exist  
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;
                                   ^
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottiePackage.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
public class LottiePackage implements ReactPackage {
                                      ^
  symbol: class ReactPackage
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottiePackage.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
  @Override public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
                                                          ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
  location: class LottiePackage
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottiePackage.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
  @Override public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
                        ^
  symbol:   class NativeModule
  location: class LottiePackage
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottiePackage.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
  public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
                              ^
  symbol:   class JavaScriptModule
  location: class LottiePackage
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottiePackage.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
                                              ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
  location: class LottiePackage
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottiePackage.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
              ^
  symbol:   class ViewManager
  location: class LottiePackage
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:192: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "sourceName")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:205: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "sourceJson")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:210: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "cacheComposition")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:215: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "resizeMode")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:228: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "renderMode")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:241: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "progress")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:246: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "speed")
   ^
  symbol:   class ReactProp
  location: class LottieAnimationViewManager
C:\Web\startrucks\node_modules\lottie-react-native\src\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\lottie\LottieAnimationViewManager.java:251: error: cannot find symbol
  @ReactProp(name = "loop")
```

Informações:

```
System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.22000
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
    Memory: 10.10 GB / 19.91 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.14.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
    Yarn: 1.22.17 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
    npm: 7.6.0 - ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.CMD
    Watchman: Not Found
  SDKs:
    Android SDK: Not Found
    Windows SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Version     2020.3.0.0 AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000
    Visual Studio: 16.8.30907.101 (Visual Studio Community 2019)
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.13
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: ^7.0.3 => 7.0.3
    react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
    react-native: 0.67.2 => 0.67.2
    react-native-windows: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Package:

```
"scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.17",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^7.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^5.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^14.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^14.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^14.3.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "card-validator": "^8.1.1",
    "cpf-cnpj-validator": "^1.0.3",
    "lottie-ios": "3.2.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.67.2",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^7.3.0",
    "react-native-dash": "^0.0.11",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.4.9",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.30.1",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^4.3.7",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.2",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.66.15",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.10",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Alguém já passou por isso, sabe como resolver?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Aplique o seguinte [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)

Path

```
patches/@react-native-community+cli-platform-android+4.10.1.patch
```

Patch

```
diff --git a/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js b/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js
index 302dbd7..f4f7607 100644
--- a/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js
+++ b/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js
@@ -181,7 +181,15 @@ function buildAndRun(args, androidProject) {
   }
 }
 
-function runOnSpecificDevice(args, gradlew, packageName, adbPath, androidProject) {
+function getTaskNames(appName, commands) {
+  return appName ? commands.map(command => `${appName}:${command}`) : commands;
+}
+
+function toPascalCase(value) {
+  return value !== '' ? value[0].toUpperCase() + value.slice(1) : value;
+}
+
+function runOnSpecificDevice(args, cmd, packageName, adbPath, androidProject) {
   const devices = _adb.default.getDevices(adbPath);
 
   const {
@@ -190,7 +198,7 @@ function runOnSpecificDevice(args, gradlew, packageName, adbPath, androidProject
 
   if (devices.length > 0 && deviceId) {
     if (devices.indexOf(deviceId) !== -1) {
-      buildApk(gradlew, androidProject.sourceDir);
+      buildApk(cmd, androidProject, args);
       installAndLaunchOnDevice(args, deviceId, packageName, adbPath, androidProject);
     } else {
       _cliTools().logger.error(`Could not find device with the id: "${deviceId}". Please choose one of the following:`, ...devices);
@@ -200,18 +208,22 @@ function runOnSpecificDevice(args, gradlew, packageName, adbPath, androidProject
   }
 }
 
-function buildApk(gradlew, sourceDir) {
+function buildApk(cmd, androidProject, args) {
   try {
-    // using '-x lint' in order to ignore linting errors while building the apk
-    const gradleArgs = ['build', '-x', 'lint'];
+    const tasks = args.tasks || ['install' + toPascalCase(args.variant)];
+    const gradleArgs = getTaskNames(args.appFolder || androidProject.appName, tasks)
+
+    if (args.port != null) {
+      gradleArgs.push('-PreactNativeDevServerPort=' + args.port);
+    }
 
     _cliTools().logger.info('Building the app...');
 
-    _cliTools().logger.debug(`Running command "${gradlew} ${gradleArgs.join(' ')}"`);
+    _cliTools().logger.debug(`Running command "${cmd} ${gradleArgs.join(' ')}"`);
 
-    _execa().default.sync(gradlew, gradleArgs, {
+    _execa().default.sync(cmd, gradleArgs, {
       stdio: 'inherit',
-      cwd: sourceDir
+      cwd: androidProject.sourceDir
     });
   } catch (error) {
     throw new (_cliTools().CLIError)('Failed to build the app.', error);
@@ -271,7 +283,6 @@ function getInstallApkName(appName, adbPath, variant, device, buildDirectory) {
 
 function installAndLaunchOnDevice(args, selectedDevice, packageName, adbPath, androidProject) {
   (0, _tryRunAdbReverse.default)(args.port, selectedDevice);
-  tryInstallAppOnDevice(args, adbPath, selectedDevice, androidProject);
   (0, _tryLaunchAppOnDevice.default)(selectedDevice, packageName, adbPath, args);
 }
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).